# c# winforms binding not working

Tags: winforms, data-binding

The following code works without a problem

> using System;
>   using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace ClassLibrary1 {
>       using System.Diagnostics;
>
> ```
> public class person
> {
>     public string FirstName { get; set; }
>     public string LastName { get; set; }
> }
> public partial class Form1 : Form
> {
>     public Form1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     person fred = new person();
>
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         fred.FirstName = "Fred";
>         this.textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", fred, "FirstName");
>         Debug.Assert(textBox1.Text == fred.FirstName);  // true
>     }
> } }
> ```

yet when i try a similar patttern to databind a class with many more properties,  the assertion fails.
the textbox is blank even though the bound property has data.
what could i be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

OOps, the pattern was not the same.
I was setting the DataBindings before the form was visible, and this seems to be the problem.